# Storybook documentation code only shows template

Tags: svelte, storybook

When I look at the code of my component in Storybook, I only see the template that was used for the component. The arguments (attributes) are not filled out. How can I solve this?

[image]

### Code

```html
<Meta
        title="svelte-component-kit/Heading"
        component={Heading}
        argTypes={{
          text: { control: "text" },
          level: { control: "text" },
        }}
/>


<Template let:args let:text>
    <Heading {...args}>{text}</Heading>
</Template>


<Story name="H1" args={{
        level: "1",
        text: "Hello, World!",
}}/>

<Story name="H2" args={{
        level: "2",
        text: "Hello, World!",
}}/>

<Story name="H3" args={{
        level: "3",
        text: "Hello, World!",
}}/>
```

Comment: I don't think that is how the show code is supposed to work, If It does work that way for other framworks look if they are working on adding/improving svelte support.

Comment: Yeah for the other frameworks it works. It does work when writing the story in plain JS, but not with the „native svelte“ story language. I made an issue on GitHub, but the latest commit to the svelte addon is 7 months old, so I don‘t think this will be worked on soon. Kinda sad, since this is a main feature..